# last view position changes on backpressed

Tags: android

I have 5 horizontal listviews in one fragment. I scroll down the page till end & from that position go to next fragment. Here if I add/remove data of top horizontal listview of previous fragment & go back again to that previous fragment then last view position changes(i.e I am not able to coming back at exactly same previous fragments position). What I am thinking is this is due to top horizontal listview refreshed after add/remove data from it. I tried to solve the issue with many ways, but not succeeded. Please help.

Comment: Can you post your xml so we get some ideas? Which position do you want to keep? Do you have a scrollview surrounding your list views or do you have weighted list views? Your question is not well defined, since there is 5 list views, there can be 5 positions ; or you can have scrollview surrounding your list views and you might want to keep the position of your page scroll. Do you wan't to keep all 5s positions?

Comment: What Have You Done for go to next fragment.??